# Chance of Double 1 or Double 6

Tags: conditional-probability

I'm trying to fight out what are the chances of double 1 or double 6
I know that for 2 six-faced dice (aka 2D6) the probability would be 2/36.
What are the chances for 3D6? 4D6? 5D6? and etc?

Comment: What does the notation $3D6$ mean?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I think it means 3 six-faced die; nD6 is n 6-faced die.

Comment: @user99680: correct

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have $nD6$ , i.e., that you throw n six-faced die . I am assuming also you want the probability of having *exactly* a double 1 or a double six. Then you have nP2 ways of having two die with the same outcome, each with probability $1/6$. The rest of the die must land in a face other than the repeated value, so all other $n-2$ outcomes will have probability $5/6$. Then, when you throw all $n$ die, you can have two equal outcomes in $nP2$ ways, EDIT the other $(n-2)$ throws can happen in $(6-1)^{n-2
}=5^{n-2}$ ways (the other outcomes can each be anything other than the repeated value) and the remaining $n-2$ outcomes each will have probability $5/6$ for a probability of $$nP2 (5^{n-2})(1/6)^2 (5/6)^{n-2} $$

Comment: @André Nicolas: Edited; my bad, should have been a permutation, not combination. I was also doing a different problem with the distinguishable die.

Comment: It is not clear what OP is asking for, at least one double $1$ or double $6$? Exactly one? For neither of these will the above answer be in general right.

Comment: @user99680 hmm intersting but it doesn't seem to work or I've either misunderstood?  In the first formula nC2=n!/2!(n−2)! is n = the number of dice or the number I want? Because if I plugged it in as double 1 or double 6 for 3D6 the result i get is 1.38% which is wrong?

Comment: @Eldwin: Please ignore, I was thinking of something else, let me rewrite. Sorry.

Comment: @Eldwin: Please see the latest (hopefully correct) version.

Comment: @user99680: nP2 = (1/6)^2*(5/6)^n-2? sorry not how to do the power stuff. I've inputted that formula but doesn't spit out the right results...unless I've misunderstood? Sorry been a long time since I've down probability..

Comment: @Eldwin: No it is $nP2(1/6)^2(5/6)^{n-2}(5^{n-2})$. If this is not correct, I will just delete the post; sorry for taking so much of your time. I think there may be a factor $5^{n-2}$ there two that I did not put in (which I included now).

Comment: @user99680: What's the probability of getting 1 set of doubles for n six faced dices?

Comment: @Eldwin: I am getting $nP2(1/6)^2(5/6)^{n-2}(5^{n-2})$

Comment: @user99680: Thanks for the help! I think i got it. Just need to research some of the maths reference! Thanks!

Comment: @Eldwin: Sorry for my confusion, I hope this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it is given $n$ six-sided dice, we need $2$ of them to show either both ones or both sixes, and $n-2$ of them to show anything *but* what is showing on the pair **or** the other double.

There are $n \choose 2$ ways to pick the ‘magic’ $2$ dice out of the $n$. These dice have a $\frac{1}{18}$ chance of showing either double 1's or double 6's: $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of picking a 1 or a 6 on the first throw, and a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of the second matching the first.

In the remaining $n-2$ dice, we have two possibilities. One is that the remaining dice all show something other than 1 or 6. The second is that there is at **most** one 1 or one 6 is seen—not the one selected for the ‘magic’ pair.

Case 1 should have probability ${{n-2} \choose {n - 2}}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n - 2}$

Case 2 should have probability ${{n-2} \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) {{n-3} \choose {n - 3}}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n - 3}$

The sum of these two cases is:
$$
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n - 2} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n - 3} \frac{n - 2}{6}\\
=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n - 3}\left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{n - 2}{6}\right)\\
=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n - 3}\left(\frac{n + 2}{6}\right)
$$

If correct, the probability would be:
$$
{n \choose 2}\frac{1}{18}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n - 3}\left(\frac{n + 2}{6}\right)
$$